# Can I use upsert in eloquent relation model?

Tags: laravel, upsert

I just find that laravel 8 has new multiple createOrUpdate function `upsert` and I want to know how should I deal with parent id. At this point, `upsert` doesn't fill parent object id. Is there a way that I can inject parent object id manually or should I just avoid this situation at all?

I expect `$this->childmodel()->upsert([ ..data ], [identifier fields])` can create multiple rows with auto-filled parent_id field, which is not..